# break test if-statement pass

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm writing a test that click a button that opens up a window. The function should toggle the window but sometimes you can keep on clicking "open" and more windows are appearing until memory lost.

I did a simple loop that should break the test if it count the same element more than 2 times.

This is what I have for the moment.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//*[@data-id='panel_workspace_list_panel']//*[@data-id[starts-with(.,'bookmark-')]]")]
IWebElement bookmarklist{ get; set; }

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//*[@data-id='dialog_bookmark']")]
IList<IWebElement> bookmark_dialog { get; set; }

   public void Bug2463()
     {

         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
               bookmarklist.Click();
            }

            var count = bookmark_dialog.Count();

            if (count > 2)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Any good advice :)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the number of open windows / tabs, you should use `Driver.WindowHandles.Count()` property and not count the elements, since you're counting how many elements with this XPath `".//*[@data-id='dialog_bookmark']"` do you have in your **current window DOM**.